# Blue screens of death central analysis

Tags: windows, operating-system

I wish get your recommendations for central analysis of BSODs software. I have a bunch of dumps which I wish to analyze and understand the root cause for the system crash.

Which tools/applications could I use?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure where it's written, but the rules for this site typically require some price info, whether you want to use is standalone or on a server, a web-app or similar and which features the tool must have. If possible, be a little bit more specific regarding the environment in which the tool might be used: are you a developer, service provider or an admin of an IT department?

Comment: @ThomasWeller 100% agree – and it's on our Meta: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 3):

### For IT departments

[Nirsoft Bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) is a nice tool to show the content of a BSOD the same way it was displayed on the screen. This is often sufficient to find out the data needed for googling a problem (like the STOP code etc.). This is fine if your task is mainly of IT administrative nature.

- Bluescreenview is **free**
- and **portable**

The **central** factor here is that it will collect all BSODs of one PC automatically.

The downside is: you can't do an in-depth analysis. It may be a starting point to find the right BSOD to be later analyzed in WinDbg (as [mentioned before](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/34027/1935)).

[image: Nirsoft Bluescreenview]

Answer (score 2):

### For kernel driver developers

Windows kernel crash dumps can be analyzed with WinDbg (pronounce "windebug", "windbag" or "win-dee-bee-gee").

- WinDbg is [provided by Microsoft (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) for **free**.
- Once installed, you can simply copy the directory, so basically it's even **portable**.

Regarding the **central** analysis of crashes, you can e.g. run it on a server and write [scripts (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560137(v=vs.85).aspx) to automate the analysis for you. However, note that there are dozens of potential causes and writing a good script may take some time. The `!analyze -v` command already does a lot for you.

Assuming that you're mainly interested in debugging your own software (as opposed to doing Microsoft a favor and analyzing their issues), you have to [set up your own symbol server (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309600/how-to-get-a-windows-symbol-server-set-up).

WinDbg is very **powerful** and probably the only tool up-to-date with the latest versions of Microsoft Windows, since Microsoft itself uses it for debugging the OS.

Becoming familiar with WinDbg is a hard task, though. It took me years to profoundly answer questions about it - and I do user mode debugging only. Maybe a kernel driver developer can become familiar with WinDbg a bit faster.

[image: WinDbg BSOD analysis]

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the answers the info was very helpfull and sorry for not being clear about my request to begin with.
I am familiar with both the windbg and the Bluescreenview. I am an It professional looking for the best application to analyze my organization system crashes, therefore the below requirement are important: 
• A server based application should be the best option for me. 
• It could be either free or paid where budget shouldn't be an issue.
• The most important analyses output would be (as displayed in windbg output):
o Probably caused by. 
o Process name.

Comment: @Edcoolest: ok, then your problem is more to collect the crashes from the clients, send them to you so that you can use WinDbg to analyze?