# Is there a ready-made JS timeline chart?

Tags: library, javascript, charts

I'm working on a system which purpose is monitoring employee productivity information.

Basically, an admin user can define targets for given timeframes (for instance, from 10:00h to 11:00h, team X is supposed to deliver N items) and we want to be able to see how should we be delivering in real time.

[image: What I had in mind]

What I had in mind is something like the chart above, where the blue columns tell me the targets that have been set for every timeframe, and the green block shows me in which timeframe I currently am (let's say, for instance, that the width of the green block is equivalent to a 1-hour timeframe). And so this chart would exemplify a scenario where the current time is around 13:30h, and shows me what's the current target and the targets that had been set for the day

Does anyone know if there's any JS chart I could use to display this information?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not exactly like that but there are plenty that allow you to see an overview and select a period for viewing details.

Have you done a google search?

Examples from the first page of a Google search:

- http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/range-selector
- https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart
- https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-chart-with-scroll-and-zoom/

I have used several of these including Dyngraphs and Google charts.

Comment: Well, perhaps if the OP had done something to help themselves! Anyway, I've updated the answer. They all do what the OP has asked regardless of where I got the list from. Doubtless there are others too.

Comment: ?!?! It isn't for me to choose his tools, maybe I love Dyngraphs but it is useless to him - what then? The OP asked a question and I've answered it directly. All 3 do what he asked, that answers the question. Whether they work well for him is dependent on too many factors not described in the question. It doesn't need 3 answers. If you don't like the answer, flag it for deletion. Though of course there won't be any answer at all then. Alternatively, provide a better one.

Comment: Here you go: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/388/1935

Comment: Here's an example of how it may turn out: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34024/1935

Comment: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality - A single question was asked and I've provided 3 options. "how their recommendation fulfils these requirements", While I agree I've not been especially verbose, the Q didn't really call for it. It was a very direct Q with a very direct A. Feel free to improve the A or flag it. I've better things to do I'm afraid. I was just trying to help the OP.

Comment: There's no reason for flagging. I can't improve, because I have almost zero JS experience.